# Karma Jasmine - Code Coverage does not coverring functions inside Observable's subscribe method

Tags: unit-testing, karma-jasmine, code-coverage, angular10

I am doing a Unit Test on one of the methods of component in my angular 10 project

and I saw this code:

**MessageListComponent.ts**

EDIT: updating the complete code (the answer is already in the comment of this post)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-message-list',
    template: ...,
    providers: [
        MessageService
    ]
})
export class MessageListComponent {

    constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        // other implementation
        ....
    
        this.GetAllContents();
    }
    GetAllContents() {
        if(this.subscribedMessage) {
            this.subscribedMessage.unsubscribe();
        }
        this.subscribedMessage = this.messageService.getAllContents().subscribe((data) => {
            data && data.forEach(item => this.dataList.push(item));
            // further codes here
            ...
        }, 
        () => {
            // further codes here
            ...
        });

        // further codes here
        ...
    }

}
```

and I created a spec file like so:

**MessageListComponent.spec.ts**

```
describe('MessageListComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MessageListComponent>;
    let component: MessageListComponent;
    let messageService: MessageService;
    beforeEach(() => {
        // TestBed configuration
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            ....
            providers: [
                MessageService,
                ....
            ]
        }).compileComponents();
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        messageService = TestBed.inject(MessageService);
        messageService.getAllContents = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(observableOf(<any[]>[{}]));
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MessageListComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should load', () => {
        expect(messageService.getAllContents).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

when I run the ng test --code-coverage=true

the coverage got the implementation inside `GetAllContents` method of `MessageListComponent` but the function inside the subscribe method is not getting covered by the coverage

Is there something I'm missing to get the function inside the subscribe method?

Comment: you need to test `// further codes here` of your subscribe block

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I got a fix on this with the help from my colleague. he discovered that the services were also injected in in the @Component annotation's `providers` property. removing those made my code coverage work :) btw, thank you for the help